# How to know what is the right approach to a propositional argument?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am fairly new to discrete mathematics.

I came across a question where I have the following premises:

1. $p \implies q$
2. $q \implies r$
3. $\neg r$

Based on the text, the answer is the following:

4. $\neg q$ using Modus Tollens on 2, 3
5. $\neg p$ using Modus Tollens on 1, 4

Before looking at the answer, I derived the conclusion in the following steps:

4. $p \implies r$ using Hypothetical syllogism on 1, 3
5. $\neg p$ using Modus Tollens on 3, 4

Would anyone be able to help me understand which kind of approach would be good to take and how should I decide when to use which approach?

Comment: Both work well.

Comment: Yours is quicker and slicker.

Comment: "the answer is....": ??? You never said what the _question_ was.

Comment: I will try to go for a slicker approach. Thanks!